# JavaFX how to resize a shape from Path class

Tags: javafx, path

I created a certain shape using the class Path and MoveTo and CubicCurveTo etc ...

My question is simple, how do i resize it since its not resizable ? i'm thinking of creating a copy with all the coordinates divided by a factor but there are too many coordinates.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about vector graphics is they can be scaled very easily.  Check out [setScaleX()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setScaleX-double-)  You have to also scale in the Y direction as well or it will be stretched.

Comment: It's so easy yet i didn't find it by looking for it.
Thank you so much !!

Comment: @MohamedAmineBouhadjar Note that this will also scale things like line width. Of course you could take the approach hinted at in the question, but this would require a custom treatment of every single concrete `PathElement`; This shouldn't be too much work and running every property that denotes coordinates through a scaling matrix should suffice, but if setting the scale works for you, it should definetly be preferred. Note though that there may be differences in the parent layout, since most layouts just consider the size before any transforms are applied...